# Xmldocument SelectSingleNode where id has ' in it

Tags: c#, console

Hey I'm writing an console app that should read some xml files and then translate the values.

My issue is that the only way I can find the exact node it by its id, but some of the id's have this ' symbol in it, witch is not allowed with SelectSingleNode

Do you know a way to select this type of nodes.

Here is a example of how the xml looks like

```
<messages lang="de" fontIsEmbedded="true" defaultFontName="Verdana" defaultFontSizeSmall="9" defaultFontSizeRegular="10" defaultFontSizeLarge="11" isIMELang="false">
  <m id="Paste Meeting URL">Indsæt møde-URL</m>
  <m id="Pause">Pause</m>
  <m id="Pause Local Recording">Afbryd midlertidigt optagelse</m>
  <m id="Please select 1 'Unknown dialin' and 1 attendee to merge">Vælg venligst en "Ukendt opringning" og en deltager at koble sammen</m>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SelectSingleNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netframework-4.8) notes:

> *If you have to search for a value that includes a single quote, you must enclose the string in double quotes. If you need to search for a value that includes a double quote, you must enclose the string in single quotes.*

For the given example, either of the following should work.

```
SelectSingleNode("/messages/m[@id=\"Please select 1 'Unknown dialin' and 1 attendee to merge\"]");

SelectSingleNode(@"/messages/m[@id=""Please select 1 'Unknown dialin' and 1 attendee to merge""]");
```